# Laravel FCM push notification change default sound

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, firebase-cloud-messaging, guzzle

I am not able to change the default sound of push notification on the background.

I am using Laravel 6 I have seen many similar issues on stack overflow and other forms majority of them are are not working, broken or un answered.

I am pasting my code below help me if anyone can.

```
$optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
$optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60 * 20);
$notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder(ucfirst($all_data['title']));
$notificationBuilder->setClickAction('FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY');
$notificationBuilder->setBody(ucfirst($all_data['message']))
                    ->setSound('nokia.mp3')->getBadge('42');
```

Comment: welcome to so, provide more details on what you want to do, which answers all you have tried, your desired outcome and your current outcome, also mention the packages which you are using if any(to obtain the desired result), your question lacks clarity

Comment: hey, i am using "brozot/laravel-fcm" package.